# Laravel eloquent get all from one table and one from another

Tags: laravel, select, join, eloquent

I'm fetching with `$articles = Article::all();` for an index-page (using foreach with `$articles as $article`) all of my articles in a table. Now I want to join this results with another table called 'devices' and only want add one column named 'name' to my result in $articles.
The 'id' of the devices if equal to the 'device_id' in my articles-table. 
I can make a big select with

```
$articles = DB::table('articles')
        ->join('devices', 'articles.device_id', '=', 'devices.id')
        ->select('devices.name','articles.id','articles.text', ...)
        ->get();
```

but I don't want to do this. Is there any better option to handle this?

Thank you in advance,

quantatheist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use relationship in Model

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
class Article extends Eloquent{
    public function device(){
         $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Device');
    }
}

<?php
    namespace App\Models;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
    class Device extends Eloquent{
        public function articles(){
             $this->hasMany('App\Models\Article');
        }
    }
```

And after when you get `$articles = Article::all();`
You can loop through articles

```
foreach($articles as $article){
   echo $article->device->name
}
```

Also you can eager or lazy load relationship `$articles = Article::with('device')->all();`

And more you can take all artciles for particular device

```
Device::find(1)->articles()->get()
```